# External links and effect on SEO: how can we link to relevant posts?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, backlinks, search

I have a website that wants to link to a 1000+ pages on my website (because they are all pages that extend the information on his website), but we are both afraid that this might have a negative effect on our SEO.

So, website 1 has some information and content and wants to deliver more information by linking to website 2, who has more relevant content about that particular subject. If we would link constantly to these pages like:

```
fakewebsitename1.com/first-post-name/ --> links to fakewebsitename2.com/first-post-name/
fakewebsitename1.com/second-post-name/ --> links to fakewebsitename2.com/second-post-name/
```

I don't want this to be seen as a linkfarm or so, so I was wondering what is 'too many' and what can we do to make sure this is all fine, if any of course.

Comment: "Internal links and effect on SEO" - you appear to be describing _external_ links, not "internal" links, as stated in your title? Is there anything to link these two websites? Same server? Same owner??

Comment: I don't know why I have put internal: changed it now. Thanks for that! And yes, we are using the same server. That's also checked by Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this is a matter of conjecture. There is no "one size fits all" answer here. Much depends upon the linking site/page (link source) and target page (link target), domain quality, page quality, authority, relevancy, how the link is made, and so on and so on.

For example, if MOZ thinks my site is the shiznit and wants to link to my sites more detailed pages, should I refuse this? No. Of course not. That would be foolish. The number of links would only help my site.

You would need to be sure of the sites authority, quality, and general character. For example, how long has this site existed? What is their footprint in the search engines? Do you like the site? What is their general search performance such as bounce rate, time on site, etc? Check their domain registration too.

You will also want the links to conversational and preferably within the content itself. Links such as "more" or "for additional details see..." are not good for you. Instead, you wand the site to link to you in the content or immediately below the content with full context. For example, "We recommend that you read [Why are internal links and navigation important to your site.](https://www.example.com)"

Do your research carefully before you decide. This could be a golden opportunity for you. Or it could be a bad deal. There simply is not enough detail in your question to say.

Comment: Well, my website is actually +7 years old and his is just started. We will be on the same servers (or remove, if advised against) and the idea is a mix of 'add your response on website x) (because his will not have comments) and linking through content.

Does that give more context?

Comment: I would not recommend what you are doing from a new site. It will look like manipulation.

Comment: I will take that into account. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data aboutit à level of max backlink from unique website. So first of all, if you wanna be 100% it won't hurt you : put all the link as no follow and you'll prevent from that. 
If you want to be 200% sure, you may use obfuscation on those link.

If you want to take credit a bit, negotiate a "do follow" link from the home page and other in nofollow.

If all the link are going to be do follow, don't use optimized anchor and prefer url anchor or website name or anchor like : click here, visit website.

Comment: What do you mean with "obfuscation" of a link? And what do you mean with an 'optimized anchor'?

Comment: Obfuscation is a french term for transforming a link to a Javascript unreadable action for google. You can find all code in this article (need to be translated in english) https://www.410-gone.fr/seo/optimisation-on-site/maillage-interne/cocon-semantique/obfuscation.html